# Flash, AS3: Drawn objects are not the same

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, open-flash-chart

I'm playing with Open Flash Chart. Take a look at this chart:

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/line-solid-dot.php

As you can see, the rounded dot points look ugly. Some of them are more rounded, some of them less, they don't look the same, as they should. I don't know AS3 and have no idea what is the case. I checked the source code:

```
this.graphics.lineStyle( 0, 0, 0 );
this.graphics.beginFill( colour, 1 );
this.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, style.get('dot-size') );
this.graphics.endFill();
```

I tried to change the size or draw rectangles instead, but they still don't look the same. I guess the problem is somewhere else...

**EDIT**: I also noticed, that other elements also looks a little bit different (and they shouldn't) - for example axis ticks. My guess is that it is the quality problem. But when I right-click on the flash object, there is an option "quality" and the "high" is set (there is also a "medium" and a "low" to choose). Can I increase the quality level somewhere else?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem in my own flash code. Circles, even larger ones that shouldn't be constrained by pixel-perfect rendering, look like someone tried to make a circle from a piece of string. This is directly from the graphics.drawCircle function, in high quality.

Comment: ...and just discovered the reason. graphics.linestyle pixelHinting was turned on and made the circles look horrible.

Answer (score 1):

From [hollow dots](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/line-hollow.php), I came to realize there is something around each dot which separated each dot from the connecting lines & also produced blurry hollow dots.

Setting the attribute "halo_size" to 0 helped in this case.

I noticed the same gap in your sold dots examples as well. Maybe that's the problem.

---

To set stage quality, simply use:

```
stage.quality = "low";
stage.quality = "medium";
stage.quality = "high";
```

You may set it in the **main class** itself which happens to be the document class for this project.

---

I noticed that if the chart size is 400 x 400 these inconsistencies cease to exist. So the problem we see is a scaling problem & not at the place we think.

Besides, Setting line style allows a proper border around the circle. This will at least appear better.

```
this.graphics.lineStyle(1, colour, 1);
this.graphics.beginFill( colour, 1 );
this.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, style.get('dot-size') );
this.graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that's not the case. I also noticed, that other elements also looks a little bit different (and they shouldn't) - for example axis ticks. My guess is that it is the quality problem. But when I right-click on the flash object, there is an option "quality" and the "high" is set (there is also a "medium" and a "low" to choose). Can I increase the quality level somewhere else?

Comment: thx for the info, unfortunately this doesn't change anything, because quality is "high" by default. I noticed, that in version 1 of OFC everything looks as it should: http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/gallery-data.php . I thought maybe it is beacause in version 2 we use swfobject to initialize ofc, but it's not the case. I also read something about "smoothing" (flash.display.Bitmap class), but I don't know if I can somehow apply it to the code. Seems like quite a big bug in 2.0 version (2.5 community version doesn't fix it). Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I used a hack to get over this recently. Please see the edits.

Comment: Thank you. This isn't the 100% correct solution, but anyway, it looks better.